# matplotlib basemap mouse event

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

```
global testResults
testResults = []
def onclick(event):
    print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    testResults.append('Success')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,10))
axes.set_title('Seasonality Clustering')
markerList = ['bo','go','ro','co','mo','yo','ko','wo']
m = Basemap(projection='gall',
            llcrnrlon=-130,llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlon=-65,urcrnrlat=55,resolution='i',
           lat_0=39.5, lon_0=-98.35,ax=axes)
m.bluemarble()
for index,row in siteMaster.iterrows():
    x,y = m(row['longitude'],row['latitude'])
    m.plot(x,y,markerList[int(row['Cluster2'])],markersize=10)
for index,row in siteMaster.iloc[closest].iterrows():
    x,y = m(row['longitude'],row['latitude'])
    x2,y2 = m(row['longitude'],row['latitude']+10)
    plt.annotate(row['City']+','+row['State'], xy=(x,y),xycoords='data',xytext=(x2,y2),color = markerList[int(row['Cluster2'])][0], 
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",color = markerList[int(row['Cluster2'])][0]),size=20)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to add mouse event for Basemap objects. I tried several different events but it doesn't print anything. The environment I am using is Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6. The plot can be shown successfully, but several click on the map returns nothing. And the global variable "testResults" is a empty list. What should I do to add mouse event for Basemap objects? See plot below.
[Matplotlib Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwMYf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use the inline backend in jupyter, which produces png plots. Clicking in png images does of course have no effect.

You may use the

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

backend instead, or try the

```
%matplotlib qt
```

backend.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although click not print anything. But strings are being added in to the list. I think this is enough for me to continue.

Comment: Yep, you cannot `print` anything from within an event loop in jupyter.